# Vim jump event?

Tags: vim

I edit the same files often, so I have assigned some global marks to make it easier to load them up. For example, I jump to my resume (a TeX file) by typing 'R in normal mode.

I have also set up autocommands for TeX files, triggered by the BufWinEnter event. If I type :e /path/to/resume.tex in normal mode, everything works great. Yay!

However, the BufWinEnter event does not seem to be triggered when I jump to the file using the global mark 'R. Is there some other event I should use instead? What is the right way to set this up?

Here is the relevant line of ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim

```
au BufWinEnter <buffer> silent loadview
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this wrong behavior: test `au BufWinEnter <buffer>` autocommand works for me when I jump to global mark in some .tex file. You can try `:15verbose normal 'R` to see whether your tex.vim is loaded and whether desired autocommand is executed

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `:au Syntax tex silent loadview` in `.vimrc`, instead.